# Calling setState in constructor gives warning

Tags: reactjs, react-lifecycle

I have a code written by someone else where the `constructor` where I have`state` initialized but also called the `setState` if `props` is `undefined`, the code is as below:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        subId: props.match.params.subId
    }
   if(props!==undefined){
        this.setState({
            subId: props.match.params.subId 
        });
    }
}
```

When I execute my module I get the warning in console as **warning.js:35 Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.**

I googled about it and found that the setState should not be called in constructor. But still cannot understand the thing done here in constructor and the ideal way expected by react. Need some help in understanding, whether the code done in constructor is correct, if yes, why, if no, why?

Comment: Isn't the if statement unnecessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides setting the `state` with `setState` it also has the mechanism of re-rendering on change. The constructor is executed before it is actually mounted and will not render something. That's why it makes no sense to use `setState` in the constructor.

Comment: What if I do not have props defined, where should I set the state again instead of doing it in constructor

Comment: @OMTheEternity: you can compare `props` directly inside `constructor`.  For example: `subId: props ? props.match.params.subId : 0`

Comment: Thanks @FiriceNguyen  ohhh!!! thats the moment when u forget the silly things as well :)

Comment: But if props is not defined, then does `state` gets initialised??

Comment: @OMTheEternity Don't check if prop is defined to set the state. Just set it directly with the ternary operator Firice Nguyen provided.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to already given answers I would like to note that `setState` is an async operation.

Any constructor in javascript by its nature is synchronous function that must construct and "return" instance of the class being constructed. Calling `setState` in constructor leaves you in undetermined state where you/react cannot rely upon the fact that component construction has been finished.

Comment: use this.state = {//...your state}, calling setState is changing the state before it is even set and before even component is mounted, this will go against the life cycle of react component

Answer (score 2):

The reason `setState` exists is because component's `state` is immutable, and changes to it lead to re-render the component. In the constructor, just change the state directly on `this.state`.

Also, you don't need to check if the `props` is `undefined`, `react` make sure it's an `object` for you, and when it's `undefined`, something seriously wrong happened anyway.

Comment: But if props is not defined, then does state gets initialised??

Comment: You are right. The state is always an object, the assignment in constructor just add properties to it, otherwise it's empty.